# beamer: Insert the same frame after each frame

Tags: beamer

I use Beamer for creating a presentation. I have the following frame that I want to insert after each slide.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
 \begin{centering}%
 \pgfimage[height=\paperheight]{pageGrid.png}%
 \par%
 \end{centering}%
\end{frame}
```

Is it possible. The crude way is to copy and paste after each slide but I hope there's a better way. 
Additional question: how can I suppress count pages for those added frames?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just give the frame a name and use `\againframe` after each frame. Alternatively define your own frame environment to use around all other frames that does this.

Comment: Please see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459450/number-of-slides-in-head-foot for some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could misuse the beamer note mechanism to automatically show an image after each frame. This also has the advantage that you don't need to worry about exempting them from the frame counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{%   at beginning of slide   
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%   
    \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally  empty. 
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \hspace*{-1cm}%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
   normal frame 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   normal frame 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are the best -  awesome. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rob You're welcome!