# Number of slides in head/foot

Tags: beamer

### I use the following codes

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{   
    \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
        \transsplitverticalout
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue}

\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The 
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

After compilation, I obtain

[image]

> My goal is to create a foot for the numebr of the slides with different colors i.e. the author with one color, the litle of the presentation with a second color and the number of the slide with a third color like the following:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a third box to your footline:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{   
    \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
        \transsplitverticalout
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%            \hspace*{3em}
%            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
%            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
        \end{beamercolorbox}%        
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=gray}

\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The 
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However after compilation the number of the slides does not appear. Where is the problem? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student Can you try not with your own document, but with the exact code from my answer and see if this works for you?

Comment: Yes I try with your codes but  the number of the slides does not appear.

Comment: @Student Can you try with `\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=gray,fg=red}`?

Comment: Yes now it compilates and the number appear. Thank you very much

Comment: @Student You should update your tex distribution, your beamer version is ancient!

Comment: You mean wenedit? I use the version 5.6. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Student No, not your editor but your tex distribution, probably miktex or texlive

Comment: Please when I want to ask a question, I find difficulties to paste my codes. Is there a quick manner to paste the code? Thank you very much

Comment: @Student Open the code in whatever editor you are using, select all, copy and paste it -- this is as fast as it gets.